# I am getting a Type Error in this Line

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, jupyter, ipython

```
Diff = [i - j for i,j in zip(text_features, author_signature)]
```

**Diff is a List** , 
text_features    =  [1, 2, 3] , 
author_signature =  [3, 2, 1]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting a type error because the elements of `text_features` and/or `author_signatures` are not able to be *subtracted* in the part `i - j`.

Depending on what they are, you could try converting them. For example, you could try making one or both of them numbers or strings like this:

```
Diff = [float(i) - float(j) for i,j in zip(text_features, author_signature)]   # both made into numbers

Diff = [str(i) - str(j) for i,j in zip(text_features, author_signature)]   # both made into strings (words)
```

To give better advice, you need to give an example of what your two lists are that are in the `zip()`

### EDIT

Based on the update in the question, I see that it works as expected for me:

```
In [1]: text_features = [1, 2, 3]                                                         

In [2]: author_signature = [3, 2, 1]                                                      

In [3]: Diff = [i - j for i,j in zip(text_features, author_signature)]                    

In [4]: Diff                                                                              
Out[4]: [-2, 0, 2]
```

Comment: I edited my question.  I tried float , int,  str but not working... u can test too

Comment: @Mano - see my update. It works for me!

Comment: Again, I edited my question..  very strange because I executed this code on the Jupyter notebook & getting a Type Error.

Comment: I was trying to catch the Type Error &  No Type Error found ... Hahahaha....   Thanks anyway